# Does EF .edmx create an abstract layer over the DB Foreign keys identifiers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

I  am working on an asp.net mvc web application , and I use EF to map an exsiting DB and create .edmx file.

But I am not sure about something, now inside my Development server I have the following relation, named:-

> FK_SecurityRoleGroups_Groups

[image]

But inside my staging server I got this relation named FK_Table_Table instead of FK_SecurityRoleGroups_Groups, but with the same parent and child tables and columns.
So now if I deploy my asp.net mvc web application from my Dev to testing server ,, will this cause any problem ? or the FK identifier does not matter inside the .edmx file and what really matters is the associated Parent and child tables and columns ?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build the edmx from the database the relationships get converted into what are called "Associations". Associations by default are named the same as the relationship.

The name itself isn't of technical importance and the association definition contains all the details of how the model should act and how it relates to the database. You can redefine your association names to a new standard, but it might be confusing if you're looking to match them up with the database. If you open up the edmx in notepad you can see how your associations are defined.

```
<Association Name="FK_Address_User">
    <End Role="User" Type="Self.User" Multiplicity="1" />
    <End Role="Address" Type="Self.Address" Multiplicity="*" />
    <ReferentialConstraint>
        <Principal Role="User">
            <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
        </Principal>
        <Dependent Role="Address">
            <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
        </Dependent>
    </ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

Comment: but generally speaking having different names for the association will not cause any problem , when I deploy the .edmx to another server? is this correct ?

Comment: No, the only requirement is that the name is unique. It doesn't have to match what's in the DB.